# parsing at command line works but fails in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Why would this work at the command line:

```
redis-cli info | grep instantaneous_ops_per_sec | cut -d : -f 2
```

...but not work when I assign that to a variable inside a shell script?  e.g.,

```
num=`redis-cli info` | grep instantaneous_ops_per_sec | cut -d : -f 2
```

Relatedly, why does assigning the raw output of `redis-cli info` to a shell variable and then echoing it result in a garbled version of the redis-cli output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When capturing to a variable you should put the entire chain of commands in a subshell, not just the beginning portion:

```
num=$( redis-cli info | grep instantaneous_ops_per_sec | cut -d : -f 2 )
```

Also it's better to use `$( )` rather than legacy backticks.

Comment: I swear I had tried that. :-/

Why is it that 'cat'-ing a file into a shell variable and then echoing that file results in a garbled version of that file?

Comment: @rivenmyst137 Sounds like [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)